# How can I open and keep open the command prompt from a windows form application in c++?

Tags: c++, winforms, command-prompt

I wrote a windows form application in C++ , visual studio 2010 , win7
I need to open the command prompt and then type the special command to run other program.

I use this function :

system("cmd.exe /c dir c:\");

but it is showed for a second and then disappeared! 
I use this to solve:

cin.get();

but it does not work!

also I tried this function :

char program[] = "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
WinExec((LPCSTR)program, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);

but it does not any work.

can you help me please ?

thank you so much!

Comment: Please do not create the same question multiple times.

Comment: ok! when I post the first I saw the error! so I thought I should send it again! sorry :-) how can I delete ?

Comment: you have an option to edit

Comment: @GolnazSaraji You can edit your own posts using the `edit` button under the question. Since you're new to SO you do not need to worry about it too much, but that's probably the reason you received downvotes on this one.

Comment: ok I promise u to be a very regulatory! I am actually new here ;) it is difficult a bit to act with this envioment :-) thank u again!

Answer (score 0):

use `system("cmd.exe /c dir c:\\");`

Comment: /c closes the window when done anyway.

Comment: `system("dir C:\\");` can be used instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try: `system("cmd /c dir c:\\ & pause");`